# Как правильно наследоваться в Android

Tags: android, activity

Хотел бы узнать как правильно наследоваться. 
у меня есть две активити (FeedActivity и EventActivity) 
и в обоих активити повторяется код, который написан здесь

```
public abstract class FeedActivity или EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed или activity_event);

          ЗДЕСЬ КОД, КОТОРЫЙ В FeedActivity и в EventAcitivty одинаковы.
  }
}
```

и чтоб не повторятся я создал BaseAcitivty и стер код с обоих активити и написал туда такой же, но уже в одной. Тем самым думая, что избегаю повторения в коде, что очень не люблю. Потом делал extend BaseActivity в FeedActivity и EventActivity.

Но он почему кидает мне NullPointerExseption...

Не могли бы посоветовать, как правильно наследоваться от другой активити. 
Есть ли какие нибудь предложения. Рад буду рассмотреть!

EventAcitivty

```
public class EventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_rigth_arrow);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Toast.makeText(EventActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });

}...
```

FeedActivity

```
public class FeedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected final String[] mTabNames = {"Everything", "Favo.rites"};
protected ArrayList<Fragment> mTabFragments;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
} ...
```

Comment: Проблема в вашем коде, а не в наследовании. Приложите код и стектрейс ошибки. И среда разработки к данному вопросу никакого отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Твой код, который ты вынес, работает с элементами из `R.layout.activity_feed` или `R.layout.activity_event`. Код, который ты вынес в `BaseActivity` выполнится раньше, чем на активити отобразится лэйоут. Значит все объекты, которые ты попытаешься достать из лэйота будут null.

Чтобы решить проблему, делай `setContentView` также в `BaseActivity`

Comment: @Ilyinа как в BaseActivity сделать setContentView и для FeedActivity И для EventActivity ??

Comment: Проверять текущее активити на пренадлежность к классу с помощью instanceOf. Но это плохое и костыльное решение. Опиши мне целиком задачу, которую ты пытаешься решить. Что это за две активити, для чего они нужны, что между ними общего? Я попытаюсь подсказать правильное решение

Comment: @Ilyinа Есть две activity: EventActivity и FeedActivity я их добавил в свой вопрос. И не хочу повторять код в обоих активити в onCreate.  И думал получится наследоваться.

Comment: Я понял, ты хочешь, чтобы у тебя на двух экранах были Toolbar и Drawer. Если ты хочешь использовать именно activity, то без дублирования кода тебе не обойтись. Правильное решение выглядит вот так: 1) Заведи одну активити и назови её NavigatorActivity, т.е. экран для навигации. Перенеси в него весь код связанный с тулбаром и дроером 2) Заведи лэйоут для этой активити. Лэйоут будет содержать в себе тулбар, Drawer, и FrameLayout. 3) Зведи два фрагмента - EventFragment и FeedFragment. там будешь писать свой код. Итог: код, который повторялся у тебя, будет выполнен 1 раз в NavigatorActivity

Comment: И да, при работе с приложением ты просто будешь устанавливать свои фрагменты во FrameLayout своей активити. Это не только правильно, но и быстрее, т.к. инициализация активити уступает фрагментам в скорости